# Is it possible to debug code that is being unit tested in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I have some code that is failing tests, but I can't understand why. I made the error of making a big chunck of code without making tests first / making tests during the coding. Now it simply doesn't work and I'd like to know if it is possible to put break points or something in the code that is failing so I can check on what is happening in there.

Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Test menu option there is a Debug option where you can select what you'd like to run / debug. Then you put a break point in the code and step through as you normally would.

Answer (score 0):

When in context in Visual Studio You can right click to "Run Test".

Unlisted in the context menu is also a "Debug Test".

You can add this through the tools -> options -> keyboard and search for Test.DebugTestsInCurrentContext.

However the short combination for it exists independently of the item actually being visible in the menu. When in a [TestClass] or a [TestMethod] you can use ctrl+R ctrl-T (I remember this as run test), which will debug the class or method at the cursor point.